# How to unban a user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I know how to ban members and I know how to kick them, but I don't know how to unban them. I have the following code which outputs the error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'id'

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Moderator")
async def unban2(ctx):
    mesg = ctx.message.content[8:]
    banned = client.get_user_info(mesg)
    await bot.unban(ctx.message.server, banned)
    await bot.say("Unbanned!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [unban](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.unban) a user, you need their **[user object](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User)**. The way you seem to be doing it is by passing a **user_id** in your command and then creating the **user object** based on that. You could also do it using [get_bans()](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_bans) explained below, but I'll answer your question first.

### Passing user_id in command

In your code, `mseg` is the **user_id** and `banned` is the **user object**.

```
mesg = ctx.message.content[8:]
banned = await client.get_user_info(mesg)
```

Edit: As squaswin pointed out, you need to await `get_user_info()`

You are defining **user_id** as `ctx.message.content[8:]`, which in this case is the text in your message from the **8th** character onward with **the first character being 0**.

Based on your code, the following should work:

(The numbers below are just to show character position)

```
!unban2 148978391295820384
012345678...
```

The problem with this is if your command name or prefix changes length, then you'll have to change the index in `ctx.message.content[8:]` to line up with the **user_id** in your message.

The better way is to pass **user_id** as an argument to your command:

```
async def unban(ctx, user_id):
    banned = await client.get_user_info(user_id)
```

Now you can use it directly with `client.get_user_info()`.

### Using get_bans()

You could instead use [get_bans()](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_bans) to get a list of banned users, and then use that list to get a valid **user object**. For example:

```
async def unban(ctx):
    ban_list = await self.bot.get_bans(ctx.message.server)

    # Show banned users
    await bot.say("Ban list:\n{}".format("\n".join([user.name for user in ban_list])))

    # Unban last banned user
    if not ban_list:
        await bot.say("Ban list is empty.")
        return
    try:
        await bot.unban(ctx.message.server, ban_list[-1])
        await bot.say("Unbanned user: `{}`".format(ban_list[-1].name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await bot.say("I do not have permission to unban.")
        return
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await bot.say("Unban failed.")
        return
```

To turn this into a working set of commands, you could create one command to show an indexed list of banned users, and another command to unban a user based on their list index.

Answer (score 1):

[`get_user_info`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) is a coroutine. This means that it must be `await`ed in the same way as `unban` and `say`.
As a rule of thumb, unless you're actually working with generators then any generator errors you get are probably caused by not awaiting a coroutine.

```
banned = await bot.get_user_info(mesg)
```

Oh and also written in the documentation is that this function can throw an error, so it may be worth ensuring nothing goes wrong too.

```
try:
    banned = await bot.get_user_info(mesg)
except discord.errors.NotFound:
    await bot.say("User not found")
```